# Best practice for shared subsrciption billing for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, shared, subscription

I would just like to ask if there are any best practices for a shared subscription billing for iOS and Android.

Right now, we are developing a mobile app both on Android and iOS (both native sdk, not cross-platform). And we have this certain feature in the app which you need to subscribe in order to access. But this will be a shared subscription. A one time payment regardless of what device a user is using to subscribe.

Sorry, but I am not really good in explaining things so maybe I will give you a scenario. I hope it helps you to understand what I am talking about.

For example, a user has two phones, an Android phone and an iPhone. He then installed our app in both his iPhone and Android phone. Now, he opens our app in his iPhone and he wants to access that certain feature so he subscribed. With this, what we want as a developer is to make it so that when he opens the app in his android phone, he will already be able to access that certain feature since he has already subscribed when he used the iPhone app.

We are still hesitant to continue since Google and Apple have different billing schemes. But maybe there are solutions for this, or are there?

I am hoping that someone could give us light on how to do this in the best practical way possible.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing the same issues. That's what I have so far.

- There seem to be cross-platform solutions but none of them seem to work through Google Play or Apple payment methods..
- You can use your API/backend service to flag the current user subscription state and sync it across all your platforms (that might violate Apple in-app system conditions).
- I'm currently looking for a way to communicate to both Google Play and Apple in-app payment system that the item has been already bought in a different platform. There should be a way but as said, still looking for it.

We'll keep that up to date.